# How to call method of another component in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular7

[image]

I've explain the scenario in Image.

I've one **LayoutComponent**,
In which I have 1) **LeftMenuComponent** and 2) **Router-Outlet**
In side the **LeftMenuComponent** I've **LoyaltyComponent** which is coming from **Shared Folder**.

> I want to call LoyaltyComponent ngOnInit method from any component
>   inside RouterOutlet.

Please Note: LoyaltyComponent is inside Shared Folder and OrderListComponent is inside Order Folder.

Is there any way I can call cross component method or all I need is I want to refresh LoyaltyComponent from OrderList Component.

I've tried:

```
@ViewChild('Loyalty') private loyaltyComponenet : Loyalty;
```

But it is giving me undefined.

```
Also from using behaviourSubject, can I directly call ngOnInit of LoyaltyComponent?
```

**LoyaltyComponent.ts**

```
export class Loyalty implements OnInit {

    public loyaltyMet: number;
    public loyaltyThreshold: number;
    public loyaltyBarWidth: number;
    public loyaltyRequired : number;
    constructor() {
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {     
        this.loyaltyMet = Context.loyaltyMet;
        this.loyaltyThreshold = Context.loyaltyThreshold;
        this.loyaltyRequired = this.loyaltyThreshold - this.loyaltyMet;
        this.loyaltyBarWidth = this.loyaltyMet * 100 / this.loyaltyThreshold;

        if (this.loyaltyRequired < 0) {
            this.loyaltyRequired = 0;
            this.loyaltyBarWidth = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `Context` is being injected via the constructor, is that a service ?

you can have a method on that service saying "refresh" or something, that when triggered, emits a value via a simple subject.

your Loyalty component, can, oninit, subscribe to that subject, and react to it when its triggered.

as long as the `Context` service is being used as a singleton for all consumers (as in, provided once) you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If components are parent and child then use `@Input` and `@Output`, If not then use `EventEmitter`
Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57324581/2762191

Comment: You can use EventEmitter. Sample solution in the link