# Communication between two custom (angular) elements

Tags: angular, element, communication

Communication between two custom (angular) elements

Let's say there are two custom elements.

```
- login-button `<login-button id="loginbutton"></login-button>;`
- and status-login `<status-login></status-login>`
```

When the login button is pressed element `login-button` will emit the output event `loginbuttonpressed`.
Angular elements will transform this output event to a custom-event.

Then in the status-login you can then do like:

```
constructor( @Inject(DOCUMENT) document) {
    document.getElementById('loginbutton').addEventListener('loginbuttonpressed', this.loginIsPressed);
}
```

So it will listen when the custom event is dispatched, this all works great.

Question: is there another proper way to communicate between the custom elemenents with Angular elements ?

Comment: Do you have any problem with the solution you already have?

Comment: @arpitKumar it forces to set an id. Like to explore other possible options and go from there.

Cheers.

Comment: I gave already an answer to such a question here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298115/clear-concept-of-eventemitter-class/51300001#51300001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298115/clear-concept-of-eventemitter-class/51300001#51300001)

Comment: @sagat close but I like catch the events inside the custom element.

Comment: tbh I dont really get what u mean by inside the component. Usually if u use the eventemitter u have 2 components, that need to exchange data or emit events. If I have such a case, I use them in some kind of shell component like this: <shell> <comp1 (output)="outputCatched($event)"></comp1> <comp2 [input]="what came from comp1"></comp2>  </shell>

Comment: @sagat, I am talking about Custom (Angular) elements ('webcomponents').
So you compile one component to one custom element, which is seperated from the other custom elements (component). So this all works a bit different then the  concept of an Angular App. 

See https://angular.io/guide/elements for more info.

Comment: Sorry mate, now I totally understand what u mean. U are using these components as separate "Angular projects" and have an AppShell, that is just placing them, but they are totally isolated from each other. In that case, I am not able to help you :) Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Use angular EventEmitter, Emit in one component and subscribe in another component via some common service. Whenever loginBtnClick() is called event will be triggered in status component. This way you can pass data from one component to other even if they are not in parent-child relationship

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
// service
@Injectable()
export class CommonService(){
loginClicked: EventEmitter<String> = new EventEmitter<String>();
}

export class loginBtn(){
   constructor(private commonService: CommonService);

   loginBtnClick(){
      this.commonService.loginClicked.emit({data: "any data"});
   }
}

export class status(){
   constructor(private commonService: CommonService);

   ngOnInit(){
       this.commonService.loginClicked.subscribe((data) => {
           console.log(data) // {data: "any data"}
        })
   }
}
```

Comment: I am working with Angular Elements (Custom Element), each element will be isolated in the end. So this will not work.

Thank you for  an answer.

Comment: OP is using two isolated Angular Elements that can't share a common service. He is explicitly asking about Event communication using DOM Events, not alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard event mechanisms from Angular, they will work nicely with not only native DOM Events but Angular Elements as well. For *dispatching* DOM Events you can use `@Output()` and for *listening* for DOM Events being dispatched on the Angular Element itself, simply use `@HostListener()`(see [here](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) for some docs).

So your status-login component would *roughly* look like this:

```js
@Component({
  //..
})
export class StatusLoginComponent {

  @HostListener('loginbuttonpressed', ['$event.detail'])
  loginIsPressed(detail?) {
    // use detail from CustomEvent('loginbuttonpressed')
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Event emitters help with communication between parent - sibling.

**Document**: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Observers help with the communication between elements everywhere. However you should import the observable in the component you emit and in the component that subscribes.

**Document**: https://angular.io/guide/observables

Try to avoid vanilla javascript for selecting elements. JS logic is fine, but all the DOM manipulations should be handled by angular, not written by hand. This after all is the purpose of frameworks such as Angular

Comment: Output event emit works so I have no problem there. It's more how to read the event inside another Custom Element (Angular element).

Comment: OP is clearly asking about communication between Custom / Angular Elements. Obviously it is not about communication **inside** one Angular application but between different bootstrapped isolated Angular Elements. There is no need for Observables at all.